# Can you conduct a linear regression in r with an independent variable with only one level?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, linear-regression

Can you conduct a linear regression in r with an independent variable with only one level?

I'm interested in running a linear regression with a dataset (e.g., cars) with the 1 independent variable (e.g., "speed" in mph) that only has one 1 level (e.g., fast) and 1 dependent variable (e.g., "dist" in miles) with many possibilities because it is continuous (e.g., 5, 10, 11, etc...).

Here is an example of the r code I'm using:

```
linearMod <- lm(dist ~ speed, data=cars)
```

When I run this code I get this response in the r console:

*"Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :
contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels"*

I'm not sure if this can even be run, but I don't know for sure. Please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? A linear model tells you whether, and to what extent, the mean of a dependent variable changes as the independent variable changes. You're saying you have an independent variable that doesn't change and a dependent variable that does. The concept of a regression doesn't make sense here. You could say that at a factor level of "fast", the mean of `dist` is `mean(dist)` in your whole data set. What was it you were hoping to do?

Comment: You supposed to get one vertical line at x=fast (whatever value it is), you don't need any lm machinery to get there, there is no variation in `x`

Comment: I disagree that this is meaningless. Yes, it is equivalent to something simple, and there's no need to bring the linear regression machinery into play. However, ideally `lm` would just return that simpler result, instead of rejecting the input. It is quite useful for functions to do the simple thing when it's a degenerate special case, since it means the caller doesn't have to watch out for any number of special conditions. For what it's worth.